# Seam 2, how to get the servletcontext?

Tags: java, seam, servlets, seam2

I'm in seam 2. How can I get the servlet context?

I can do this:
ServletContexts servletContexts = ServletContexts.getInstance();

But this is not the ServletContext.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending at what moment you are trying to get the `ServletContext`:

- During a `HttpServletRequest` request: `ServletContexts.instance().getRequest().getServletContext()`.
- During JSF request: `(ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()`.
- During application startup: `ServletLifecycle.getServletContext()`.

Comment: Should be `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`